# Building your requests body based on arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was wondering the best way to build the body i will send with requests, depending on the arguments passed.

This is the scenario:

You might first build up a body like this:

```
data={
    'user': user,
    'password': password,
    'somethingelse': somethingelse,
    }
```

Okay, so those would be the required fields to post. What if the API call have 5-10 other fields that you could optionally populate?

If I would pass in *args for my post function, I could leave the optional fields empty, and populate them with the args, but if the args are empty, this will always fail. And sometimes, even if a post an optional field without any content, the API still returns an error, because it expects a value.

**UPDATE**
A bit more information was needed, so let me try to explain.

I am working these days a lot with different REST API's, and it often happens I start discussing with myself, how I am supposed to design all the different POST/GET functions.

Take this example:

```
  def search(self, query, ??):
    """
    Executes a searchquery, that is then stored and needs
    to be called again to get results, using the returned
    search_id.
    :param query: Query to be run with the search
    :return: Array of the current searchid, which is needed
             for other functions, and the content of HTTP response.
    """
    search_id = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    if len(args) > 0:
        response = self._post(
            '/server/search', data={
                'query': query,
                'search_session_id': search_id,
                'user_session_id': self.token,
            })
```

In this example, `start_time` and `end_time` could be included in this request, as the parameters is both optional, though they both have to exist if they are used.

Then I think, how am I going to design this, so the user has the option of both using the optional parameters, or decide to just stay with the defaults.

Now the question is, how would i insert the optional parameters here, only if they are needed or requested? Should i never store the key parameters in the function to begin with, and always parse all key and value elements when calling the function instead? Would anyone be so kind as maybe let me know about a few different way to achieve this?

If someone would need any more information about my thought, please let me know.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `def function(**kwargs)` syntax?

Comment: @Patrick kinda, would you day then that all data and keys should be transferred through kwargs** ? I see no reason why this should be downvoted though, but okay.

Comment: It's pretty vague what you're trying to do.  There aren't going to be many concrete answers without more details from you

Comment: @PatrickHaugh okay i tried to add some more to my question, under UPDATE: Please let me know if i should be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was contributed by @Antti Haapala in the python chat room.

Leaving the static data in the post requests itself is fine, and adding the support for keyword arguments (**kwargs) in requests can be done 2 ways in python 2.7, either by merging the data before sending it to the post request like so:

```
def search(self, query, **kwargs):
    """
    Executes a searchquery, that is then stored and needs
    to be called again to get results, using the returned
    search_id.
    :param query: Query to be run with the search
    :return: Array of the current searchid, which is needed
             for other functions, and the content of HTTP response.
    """
    search_id = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    data ={
        'query': query,
        'search_session_id': search_id,
        'user_session_id': self.token,
    }
    data.update(kwargs)
    response = self._post('/server/search', data)
    return search_id, response.json()
```

Or by changing the data to a dict, before adding the **kwarg values:

```
def search(self, query, **kwargs):
    """
    Executes a searchquery, that is then stored and needs
    to be called again to get results, using the returned
    search_id.
    :param query: Query to be run with the search
    :return: Array of the current searchid, which is needed
             for other functions, and the content of HTTP response.
    """
    search_id = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    if len(args) > 0:
        response = self._post(
            '/server/search', data=dict(
                query=query,
                search_session_id=search_id,
                user_session_id=self.token,
                **kwargs
            ))
    return search_id, response.json()
```

In python 3, you would be able to add it directly, instead of merging, or changing the variable into a dict.